# yarn build --production causes error while yarn build not

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg

I am trying to figure out why, when I try to `yarn install --production`  and then `yarn build` my `ts` react app it causes
`Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router-dom'. '..../node_modules/react-router-dom/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.` while it's already included in deps:

[image: deps]
[image]

while `yarn install` and then `yarn build` succeeds.

Comment: These are dev dependencies. Please show depdendcies too

Comment: I have updated with dependencies. I installed  yarn add @types/react-router-dom  and it lies down to the dev deps.

Answer (score 0):

include the types package in your root index.d.ts file. You can do this with any @types package that isn't paired with its sans @type/ dependency equivalent

you can use this approach for things like analytics and sdks

it compiles the defs into output making it available in production

you must also set "declaration": true` in tsconfig.json

```js
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": "true",
    "declaration": true,
    "...": "..."
  },
  "include": ["index.d.ts", "src/**/*", "..."]
}
```

here's my root index.d.ts from a current project

```
/// <reference types="facebook-js-sdk" />
/// <reference types="facebook-pixel" />
/// <reference types="google.maps" />
/// <reference types="google-libphonenumber" />
/// <reference types="gtag.js" />
/// <reference types="glob" />

declare module "facebook-js-sdk";
declare module "facebook-pixel";
declare module "google.maps";
declare module "google-libphonenumber";
declare module "gtag.js";
declare module "glob";

interface Window {
  dataLayer?: object[];
}
```

In an additional tsconfig file (tsconfig.build.json),extend your main tscnfig.json then call for paths to `exclude`

- tsconfig.build.json

```json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

Note:

once you declare the package, you no longer need to import types provided by that package. They are injected and available globally for consumption